# <Span> not block text

Tags: html, css, cordova

I have a list, that displays different actions for users to click on. And I have a "badge" that is next to text that I float right to display a number. The issue is that my text before the badge does not wrap.

```
insert = "<a href=\"#!\" class=\"collection-item\" id=\"" + data[i].id + "\"><h5 class = \"orange-text text-darken-2\"> " + name + "  <span class=\"badge green white-text\">" + score + "pts</span></h5> <p>" + distance + " miles" + " </p></a>";
```

That prints each entry in the list. As you can see my text which is inserted with `name` gets behind the green badges from the span:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this css snippet. It wraps and put some ellipsis at the end:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

UPDATE:

Here is a real world example from one of my apps.

HTML:

```
<ul class="panelList">
    <li class="receipt">
        <span class="glyphicons bin"></span>
        <span class="listcounter"></span>
        Dinkelbrötchen über Nacht
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.panelList {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.panelList li {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The «bin» span is a trash for deleting and the «listcounter» is a working timer in the list. The order of elements is other than in your app, but the some problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that just wrap it in the div that the span is in and the span would still stay on top?

Answer (score -1):

Try http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

```css
word-wrap: break-word;
display:block
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just wrap it in the div that the span is in and the span would still stay on top?